# COUNT function in sql counting whole data in database

Tags: php, arrays, select, count

I am trying to count the number of data in the database according to the category id and I have written the following lines of code:

```
public function getPodcastByCategoryId($catId){
    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
                    'podcast.id', 
                    'podcast.title',  
                    'podcast.description', 
                    'podcast.duration',
                    'podcast.audio',
                    'podcast.image',
                    'podcast.category',
                    'podcast.added_date',
                    'categories.title AS category_title',
                    '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = podcast.added_by) as author',
                    '(SELECT COUNT(category) FROM podcast WHERE category = podcast.category) as episodes'
                ),
        'join'   => "LEFT JOIN categories on podcast.category = categories.id",
        'where' => array(
            'category' => $catId
        ),
    );
    return $this->select($args);
}
```

However, the function `getPodcastByCategoryId($catId)` is giving episodes = 3 which is the count of data present in table podcast.

**Data in database**:

[image: data in database]

My expected episodes would be 2 in category id 2 and 1 in category id 1.

Comment: Why not `INNER JOIN`s to `users` & `categories` instead of sub queires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for episode you should use   COUNT(*)

```
$args = array(
      'fields' => array(
                  'podcast.id', 
                  'podcast.title',  
                  'podcast.description', 
                  'podcast.duration',
                  'podcast.audio',
                  'podcast.image',
                  'podcast.category',
                  'podcast.added_date',
                  'categories.title AS category_title',
                  '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = podcast.added_by) as author',
                  '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM podcast WHERE categories.category = podcast.category) as episodes'
              ),
      'join'   => "LEFT JOIN categories on podcast.category = categories.id",
      'where' => array(
          'category' => $catId
      ),
  );
```

Comment: It will return count 2 for all category ids.

Comment: `Distinct` would not be needed now I guess.

Comment: @SougataBose   . correct   should be a count(*) not distinct category